# Java - Is there a "convertible" interface?

Tags: java, interface

Is there an existing interface (or abstract class) that allows you to define conversions between two different types?
You would implement (or extend) it, and for example, you can convert between a `Foo` and a `Bar`.

Example Interface:

```
public interface ConvertibleInterface<T, U> {
    public U to(T item);
    public T from(U item);
}
```

I was just wondering if something like this exists in the java system libraries.

Comment: No. Under Java generics this might not make such sense either, as it would only allow one T/U pairing. (.NET has quite a Converter system, but I don't know of anything similar in core Java.)

Comment: There's nothing in the standard library, but the Spring type-conversion system has interfaces for these operations and support classes for handling conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the new `Function<T, U>` type to define something that would convert to and from the given type:

```
Function<String, Integer> toInt = (String in) -> Integer.parseInt(in);
Function<Integer, String> toString = (Integer in) -> in.toString();

Integer converted = toInt.apply("101");
```

See the [API docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). This has been added in Java 8, so make sure you are up to date.

Comment: For Java 7 and below, Guava has a `Function` with the same name, but of course it'd also be a rather simple interface to implement yourself.

Comment: The advantage of Guava's interface is that it works with a number of the other Guava utilities as well.